# Component is missing when using Platform.select in JSX javascript expression: e.g. return (<>{Platform.select({})}</>);

Tags: react-native

I am not able to use Platform.select() in javascript expressions in JSX (curly braces) successfully. The app still compiles, but the **component is missing**. If I directly call the select function, it works, as shown under `// Works`. **Does this happen because the Platform.OS 'key' does not get passed in when inside JSX expressions?** The Platform module docs is [rather limited?](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html)

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Platform, Text} from 'react-native';

// Does not work:
const PlatformText = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      {Platform.select({
        ios: () => <Text>IOS</Text>,
        android: () => <Text>Android</Text>,
      })}
    </View>
  );
};

// Works:
const PlatformText = Platform.select({
  ios: () => <Text>IOS</Text>,
  android: () => <Text>Android</Text>,
});

export default PlatformText;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's happening because you are returning a function. No one is calling that callback. If you want to use that component with the `Platform.select`, just directly return your desired component:

```
const PlatformText = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      {Platform.select({
        ios: <Text>IOS</Text>,
        android: <Text>Android</Text>,
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your "*does not work*" section, you **return a function**, while in your "*works*" section, you *return the Result of Platform-Select* in straight way.

So be sure, you call your PlatformText in the right way to get the Result.